# Android XML error after updating eclipse

Tags: android, xml

After recently updating eclipse i keep getting an error saying "Attribute name "android:tools" associated with an element type "RelativeLayout" must be followed by the ' = ' character.

It says it on line 9 but there isn't any android:tool there. I've tried cleaning and restarting eclipse and still no solution. I never changed any part of the file, and the funny thing is all my other activities are the same and don't have any errors. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Edit... I fixed the problem by deleting the file and creating a new one. File must have been corrupt or something. Thanks for the input everyone, sorry for the run confusion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backtext"
    tools:context=".Brakes"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/brakes1"
        android:textColor="@color/textviews"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="@string/brakes2"
        android:textColor="@color/textviews"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/brakes3"
        android:textColor="@color/textviews"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/brakes4"
        android:textColor="@color/textviews"
        android:textSize="15sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Press `ctrl-shift-s` and then go to `Project -> Clean`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

to your `ScrollView` instead of the `RelativeLayout` where it is now.

it looks like your `RelativeLayout` used to be your root view, and you added the ScrollView at some point later.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I tried what you said but it still gives me the same error. I cleaned it after as well, maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your root parent,please include it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your RelativeLayout. There should be only one of those at the layout root element.

Comment: Sorry, you also need to move `tools:context=".Brakes"` from the RelativeLayout to the ScrollView, along with the `xmlns:tools` attribute. The `context` attribute should also be on the root element.

Comment: Try this instead of your ScrollView and RelativeLayout opening tags: <ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".Brakes" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >